# Cannot initialise a Symfony 2 project on a remote host: memory issue

Tags: symfony-2.1

I just installed Symfony 2 on my remote host.

But when I run web/app_dev.php I get a

> Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 16777216 bytes exhausted (tried to
>   allocate 4864 bytes) in
>   /srv/disk5/1000098/www/foi-skripte.com/vendor/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/lib/classes/Swift/Events/EventDispatcher.php
>   on line 76

Do I have to switch my hosting provider or can this be fixed?

Because it seems to me that I can't even allocate 16MB's for Symfony 2 to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears the problem was memory_limit of the script in php.ini.